# AJAX call reloads the current page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to update a div with information received from a server periodically. The code below will receive the correct information from the server, append it to the divs text, then reload the page/clear out the div.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<script type='text/javascript'>

function exec(command){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML + "<br/><br/>" + xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "HAS-sync.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send()
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 141px; height: 390px">Managers<br /> DHTs</td>
        <td name="targetThing" style="height: 390px">
            <form onsubmit="exec()">
                <input class="auto-style1" name="Text1" type="text">
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
            <br />
            <div id="txtHint" style="border:1px solid black;width:50%;height:50%"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I get this to simply append the result of the ajax call to the divs text, instead of clearing it completely?

Comment: `onsubmit` is a form action, not an input action. Your form needs to `return false` (and that binding should actually be in the `<form>` tag).

Comment: Sorry, I had posted a previous version of this files code when asking the question. I have it written to append data instead of replace, and the onsubmit is in the form tag now. It is still clearing everything from the div when the alert message box is closed.

Comment: ajax calls do not refresh the page.

Comment: I did not think that they did, however when I type into the textbox and hit enter(or press submit), the correct data is appended to the divs text, alertbox pops up with the same data, and when that alert is close, everything resets. The div gets cleared, and the URL of the page lists the get parameters as if I had submitted it to the current page instead of the target 'HAS-sync.php' server page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First move the onsubmit to the form tag instead of the input as said in the comment.

```
<form onsubmit="updateTxt(this.value);return false">
```

You need to append the response text instead of overwriting what is already in `innerhtml`.

```
document.getElementById("txtToUpdate").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: Putting the return false into the forms tag solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are overwriting the HTML using the `=` assignment. You need to append it, instead, using `+=`:

```
document.getElementById("txtToUpdate").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false` in your `onsubmit` handler so the browser knows you've handled the request and it should not proceed. This can be done in a couple ways:

Add `return false;` after `exec()` in your binding:

```
<form onsubmit="exec();return false;"><!-- ... --></form>
```

or, Modify your binding to be `return exec()` and have the method `return false;`:

```
<script>
  function exec(){
    /* ... */
    return false;
  }
</script>
<form onsubmit="return exec()"><!-- ... --></form>
```

As an aside, you should consider moving away from binding javascript using attributes and start using `addEventHandler` (and alike) to keep a clear separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var txtToUpdate = document.getElementById("txtToUpdate");
txtToUpdate.innerHTML = txtToUpdate.innerHTML + xmlhttp.responseText;
```